# Running python as a different user causes permission error

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.4

I have a python script that is intended to be run as the user `iron_nads`. The user doesn't have a shell or credentials:

```
[master_bones@everest ~]$ grep iron_nads /etc/passwd
iron_nads:x:36000:36000:iron_nads user.:/var/empty/iron_nads:/sbin/nologin
```

This user can successfully list /var/log:

```
[master_bones@everest ~]$ sudo -u iron_nads /bin/ls /var/log/
maillog
cron
messages
```

However, when I try the same command in a Python interpreter, I get a permission denied:

```
[master_bones@everest ~]$ sudo -u iron_nads python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/ls', '/var/log'], shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 419, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 993, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Interestingly, `os.listdir()` works:

```
>>> os.listdir('/var/log')
['maillog', 'cron', 'messages']
```

I tried using shell=False like so:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['/bin/ls', '/var/log'], shell=False)
```

I also tried:

```
>>> subprocess.call('/bin/ls /var/log', shell=True)
```

Unfortunately, both result in the same `Permission denied` error.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior for [`os.stat(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)?

Comment: Just to be sure. Your 1st example shows `subprocess.call(['/bin/ls'])`, but that would execute in the current directory, which was `master_bones` home. That could result in a permission denied error. Also please not that "*If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.*" so second example is also incorrect. It executed `/bin/ls` only `/var/log` was passed as an argument to shell. Could you try `subprocess.call(['/bin/ls', '/var/log'])` or `subprocess.call('/bin/ls /var/log', shell=True)`?

Comment: Apologies. I've updated my question.

Comment: @lukasGraf Using os.stat('/var/log') works.

Comment: Could you try this : 
    `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-l' ,'-c', 'echo $USER'])`



And this : 
    `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', '-u' ,'iron_nads', '/bin/ls', '/var/log'])`

Comment: @rvraghav93 Thanks but both suggestions resulted in the same error: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: x in the output of `grep iron_nads /etc/passwd` indicates the presence of an encrypted password stored in `/etc/shadow` file Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) . and `/sbin/nologin` indicates the user has been disabled. See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-binfalse-vs-sbinnologin-deny-login/) -- Perhaps something to do with these ?